# Windows 8.1 enterprise side loaded app windows launch contract was blocked with error 0x80073CFC

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, sideloading

I have a store app that is side loaded in windows 8.1 enterprise device, that device is 
a.

1. Domain joined.
2. “Allow all trusted apps to install” policy setting is enabled.
3. App is signed by a Thawte certificate which is by default a trusted root certificate.

Installation of the app was successful but ever time user launches the app, windows throws an error that it cannot open the app.

Below error is logged in the event viewer:

*Activation of the app  for the windows.launch contract was blocked with error 0x80073CFC because its package is in state: 17*

I tried uninstall and reinstall but still no luck. Any guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, ended up reimaging the device.

Comment: Thanks, it's really strange. don't know what causes it and don't know how to fix it. Probably need do a reimaging too.